# AngularJS/NodeJS Application Integration with Paypal In-Context Checkout

Tags: angularjs, node.js, paypal

I have a web application, AngularJS on the UI and NodeJS on the backend.

I want to implement the Paypal In-Context Checkout feature, but I don't really understand what are the steps to do so, the documentation is very confusing.

Can someone please explain me what are the steps to achieve this, what is need to be done on the Front-End and what on the Back-End.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three ways to do it

1 you can use client side rest.
2 you can use server side rest.
3 you can use braintree sdk.

for first steps paypal has checkout.js.
for second steps use paypal rest api basically backend task.

for both first and second steps process is quite similar.

```
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
const payments = paypal.v1.payments;
let env = new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment('app-id', 'secret');

let client = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(env);
```

create payment post request like below

```
var create_payment_json = {
                    'intent': 'sale',
                    'payer': {
                        'payment_method': 'paypal'
                    },
                    'redirect_urls': {
                        'return_url': 
                          'http://localhost:4150/test/paymentSuccess',
                          'cancel_url': 'http://cancel.url'
                    },
                    'transactions': [{
                        'item_list': {
                            'items': [
                                {
                                    'name': 'item',
                                    'sku': 'item',
                                    'price': '1.00',
                                    'currency': 'USD',
                                    'quantity': 1
                                }

                            ]
                        },
                        'amount': {
                            'currency': 'USD',
                            'total': '1.00'
                        },
                        'description': 'This is the payment'
                    }]
                };

                let request = new payments.PaymentCreateRequest();
                requestt.requestBody(create_payment_json);


                let mrrrr;
                client.execute(requestt).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                    console.log(response.result);

                    _.map(response.result.links, (value) => {
                        if (value.rel === 'approval_url') {
                            // reply.redirect(response.result.links[i].href);
                            mrrrr = value.href;
                            console.log('mrrrr', mrrrr);
                            // return reply.redirect(mrrrr);
                        }
                    });
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error.statusCode);
                    console.error(error.message);
                });
```

once payment created you will get url, redirect that url and do payment with paypal, it will return call to success url with query parameter payment id and payerId.

now in get success write below code

```
console.log('this is  query parameters', request.query);

                const payerID = request.query.PayerID;
                const paymentID = request.query.paymentId;

                const execute_payment_json = {
                    'payer_id': payerID
                };

                let ww = new payments.PaymentExecuteRequest(paymentID);
                ww.requestBody(execute_payment_json);

                client.execute(ww).then((response) => {
                    console.log('success', response.statusCode);
                    console.log('success', response.result);

                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error.statusCode);
                    console.error(error.message);
                });
```